# Microservice architecture, does it really encourage copy / paste?

Tags: architecture, microservices

I'm working in middle size organisation. From about a year we started refactor our old solution creating microservices. For backend part Go was chosen, for front we have Node.js

Now imagine that we have some html form where user puts some data. After it front end part makes own validation and call one of three different endpoints (three different microservices).

This validated by front end data then is validated by three micro services separately. The same rules are copy/pasted. And there are a lot of other examples like this.

I proposed to create some validator service that will perform validation in one place and I got the answer something like 'in microservices architecture we cannot create strong dependencies'

My question is if 'strong dependencies' are really so bad that we need to do stupid copy/paste and moreover create a unit tests for copy/pasted code (we copy/paste them too and change the names). If 'strong dependencies' are so bad could you give some examples why.

Comment: Why not create the validation libraries and then just import it where are needed?, one thing is to have microservices, but you still can have shared code between them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question, the answer is you shouldn't ever have to "copy/paste" anything, and elimination of "hard" synchronous dependencies between your services has nothing to do with it.  It's a strong sign that the functional boundaries of your monolithic decomposition are faulty.  My question to you now would be why you are doing validation on the same data with three separate services when a single microservice is supposed to own and manage its own data?  Also, it's common to have some near cross-cutting utility-type concerns that more than one microservice may share, and a common library (JAR in the case of Java for example) does not violate the intent of the architecture. No copy/past needed.

Now here is why "strong" synchronous dependencies are generally a bad idea.  The intent of microservice architecture is to quickly deploy new and improved "single/do-one-thing) features into production with a minimum of risk and without adversely impacting performance. It enables evolutionary improvement, and accelerates time-to-market of desired features. If your new service misbehaves, it only affects the functionality it is responsible for - nothing else. Now imagine if you decompose your monolithic application by "code-module" rather than by feature/function. You only end up with a distributed monolith! Not only do you loose all the advantages and intent of the architecture, but performance and complexity would also be adversely impacted to perhaps a fatal degree.

Comment: Yip faulty breakdown of functionality. This is why governance in any service based/ service oriented architecture is critical. Ensuring that there is no duplication of effort, services, operations etc.

Comment: What about form validation at front and back end side? Node.js and Go. We need for sure validate data at back side and we need a dynamic validation at front side to show this to user interactively. Do you find it as a good idea to copy paste (recreating) the same rules on both sides, create unit tests etc?

Comment: @Vitalii well, there is no other way, but the question is if you're really going to do copy/paste? With frontend that would be most probably using validations with some javascript framework, with APIs, those would be Go libraries. So while business-wise, this would be copy of the same functionality, technically wise I don't think this will be a simple copy-paste of a source code.